# Placing QR code scanner in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, qr-code

I am using an android QR code processing library - [android QR code](https://code.google.com/p/android-quick-response-code/).
 I am extending the DecoderActivity for scanner and now I want the scanner to be inside a fragment, I have used `LocalActivityManager` to embed Activity inside a fragment. Here is the code:

```
public class QrCodeProcessorFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private static final String KEY_STATE_BUNDLE = "localActivityManagerState";

private LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;

Button generate_qr_code;

private QuickPayManagerActivity parent;

protected LocalActivityManager getLocalActivityManager() {
    return mLocalActivityManager;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle state = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        state = savedInstanceState.getBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE);
    }

    mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), true);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(state);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // This is where you specify you activity class
    Intent i = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), CaptureActivity.class);
    Window w = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("tag", i);
    View currentView = w.getDecorView();
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) (currentView.getParent());
    if (vg != null)
        vg.removeView(currentView);

    currentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    currentView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    ((ViewGroup) currentView)
            .setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

    return currentView;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE,
            mLocalActivityManager.saveInstanceState());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    System.out.println("lam onresume");
    super.onResume();
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    System.out.println("lam onpause");
    super.onPause();
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchPause(getActivity().isFinishing());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchDestroy(getActivity().isFinishing());
}}
```

QR scanner is not working now. I debugged the library code, it is expecting an activity instance and I am passing the activity instance which is inside the fragment. Hope I am clear on this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library called [Barcode Fragment library](https://code.google.com/p/barcodefragmentlib) which uses a fragment for hosting the scanner functionality. Works fine but hasn't supported portrait mode support, I have done changes to library as suggested in [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178#c46). It worked like a charm :)

Comment: Can you please share the code for that ? the second link on your answer does not seems to be working anymore.